# Creating and using custom pattern on Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use custom patterns in Foundation 5.
Here is my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
        <form name="input" action="validate.php" method="post" data-abide>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Todos os campos são necessários</legend>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-3 columns">
                                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Dogecoin Adress</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="small-9 columns">
                                    <input name="wallet" type="text" pattern="wallet" class="small-12 columns" required />
                                    <small class="error">Invalid Adress</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).foundation(
        {
            abide:{
                patterns:{
                    wallet: /^D[A-Za-z0-9]{33}$/
                }
            }
        }
        );
    </script> 
</body>
```

Why when I introduce a valid adress (ex: DRzKV3Vr235MTuGuVZ4eHjZfmy4TsymDX4) it still says I have an invalid adress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes:

1. I made sure to set the type to text/javascript (some browsers may need this).
2. I added the {1} following the first D character in the regex pattern.
3. Used an updated regex pattern that should make sure all of the address characters are valid for Base58 addresses.

Edit: Fixed HTML display

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
        <form name="input" action="validate.php" method="post" data-abide>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Todos os campos são necessários</legend>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-3 columns">
                                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Dogecoin Adress</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="small-9 columns">
                                    <input name="wallet" type="text" pattern="wallet" class="small-12 columns" required />
                                    <small class="error">Invalid Adress</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).foundation(
        {
            abide:{
                patterns:{
                    wallet: /^D{1}[5-9A-HJ-NP-U]{1}[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{32}$/
                }
            }
        }
        );
    </script> 
</body>
```

Or you could try the following approach using jQuery's extend method to set the pattern:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
        <form name="input" action="validate.php" method="post" data-abide>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Todos os campos são necessários</legend>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-3 columns">
                                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Dogecoin Adress</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="small-9 columns">
                                    <input name="wallet" type="text" pattern="wallet" class="small-12 columns" required />
                                    <small class="error">Invalid Adress</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery.extend(window.Foundation.libs.abide.settings.patterns, {
            wallet: /^D{1}[5-9A-HJ-NP-U]{1}[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{32}$/
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Tried that still doesnt work I think its related to Foundation 5 and not de regular expression.[print screen](http://i.imgur.com/ek0op4f.png).

Comment: I edited the answer to include a possible workaround through jQuery.extend. See the following for reference: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3798

Comment: I should use both right? sinse the $(document).foundation(); allways needs to be present

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to try both, but I haven't used foundation enough to know for sure. I would try adding the $(document).foundation(); call before the jQuery.extend call and see what happens.